Extracción de información de productos variables
Estoy haciendo Web Scrapping a una pagina  donde lo que hace mi código es desplegar una cada vez más el botón de cargar más productos y una vez que se hayan desplegado todas las paginas y no exista el botón "Mostrar Más", debe leer todos los productos y luego extraer toda la información. Sucede que conté manualmente y debo extraer 209 productos pero cuando aplico el código con el driver de chrome cada vez que corro, me lee a veces 150, 156, 190, etc. Probé con el tiempo de espera de carga y todo pero sigue el problema. ¿Debería hacer algún ajuste adicional al código o aplico otro método para tener los 209 productos?. Este es mi código de ejemplo:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import pandas as pd

# URL del website
url_audio = "https://www.marcimex.com/audio-y-video"

products_audio = []

service = Service(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url_audio)

while True:
    try:
        show_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='vtex-button__label flex items-center justify-center h-100 ph5 ' and contains(text(), 'Mostrar más')]"))
        )

        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", show_more_button)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", show_more_button)
        
        # Espera explícita para asegurarse de que se carguen los productos adicionales
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.vtex-product-summary-2-x-container"))
        )
        
        time.sleep(2)  # Espera adicional para permitir que se cargue completamente la página
    except:
        break  # No hay más botones "Mostrar más", salir del bucle

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
page_products = soup.find_all('section', class_='vtex-product-summary-2-x-container')



driver.quit()


len(page_products)

